# JS window.answer is undefined on another html page

Tags: javascript, html, window, undefined

I am calculating some value in on one html page, and report that value on another html page. To pass the calculated answer to the next page I stored it in window.answer=myValue and changed the page by location.href=answer.html. On the answer.html my window.answer is undefined. What's the problem?

```
function callback() {
  if (this.id === q[i][0]) {
    correct++;
  } else {
    incorrect++;
  };
  if (i < q.length - 1) {
    i++;
    document.getElementById('question').innerText = q[i][1];
    document.getElementById('true').setAttribute('aria-valuenow', Math.floor(((correct + incorrect) / q.length) * 100));
    document.getElementById('true').setAttribute('style', "width: " + ((correct + incorrect) / q.length) * 100 + "%");
    document.getElementById('true').innerText = Math.floor(((correct + incorrect) / q.length) * 100);
  } else {
    window.answer = Math.floor(100 * (correct / q.length));
    window.location.href = "answer.html";
  }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do you save data using localStorage in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5780550/how-do-you-save-data-using-localstorage-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The window objects gets refreshed on navigation changes. Use [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage) to persist data between different pages.

to set the answer

```
window.localStorage.setItem('answer', Math.floor(100 * (correct / q.length)));
```

on answer.html

```
var answer = window.getItem('answer');
```

alternative [SessionStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/sessionStorage)

Comment: Thanks it soved the problem. The strange thing was that I could transfer window.name from one page to another but not the score :)